# Best practise: How to implement plugins for spring jpa projects?

Tags: java, spring, plugins, architecture

i always wondering what is the best practise to implement a plugin for a spring jpa project.

For example i would have such structure of java projects:

### server-core

```
@Entity
public class User {

    private String name;
    
}
```

Now i would like to have separate java projects as plugins for the server project.

### first-plugin

The first plugin is supposed to add another field to the user entity for example **users age**.

### second-plugin

The second plugin is supposed to add a new table and a relation from the new table to the users table for example:

```
@Entity
public class Usergroup {
    
    private Set<User> users;
    
}
```

### Now my question

The used database is **sql server**. Is there any good practise to realize such plugins **without make changes to the server-core project** so a plugin always can be appended and uncoupled without impacts for the server-core project? Is sql server the right database for such architecture or should i use a no-sql database instead?

Comment: Just add the plugins to the classpath and make sure they are picked up by the classpath scan?

Comment: But how to realize that the plugin can add a relationship to user entity without having the server-core project as dependency?

Comment: They can use provided/compileOnly dependencies for the core.

Comment: @dan1st thx, that looks like to be solution i was looking for!! One question i still have: once the second plugin was integraded hibernate will update shema to create new table with constraint to forein key. If i decide to remove the plugin the created table will still be there and the constraints, too. If the user will delete a user entity he will get an exception because of the constraints. Whats the best practise? Should i delete the table while removing the plugin? Or should i disable constraints on the created table so if i decide to add the plugin again the old rows will be available?

Comment: It is normally in the scope of the plugin that it does not leave anything in a corrupted state. You could make a mechanism that plugins can provide SQL scripts that gets executed once the application is started without the plugin.

Comment: I understand. Thats a nice solution. Thx. Could you post your comment/s as an answer so i can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the plugins to link/include the binaries of the original project, you can mark the original project as a `provided` (maven) or `compileOnly` (gradle) dependency:

```xml
<groupId>your.group.id</groupId>
<artifactId>server-core</artifactId>
<version>your-core-version</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
```

```
compileOnly your.group.id:server-core:your-core-version
```

Adding this to the build configurations of the plugin means that `server-core` is available when compiling the plugin but it will not be included in binaries (like fat JARs).

If you fear that a plugin corrupts your database and that it won't work when removing the plugin, this is the responsibility of the plugin.

If you want to make custom login that is executed when the plugin is removed, you can include an API for this (e.g. plugins can contain sql scripts with certain names, those are saved when the plugin loads and will be executed if the program is started without the plugin).

However, plugins should not change your core data structure or add constraints to existing tables used by the core dependency anyways.

Instead, the plugins should access other tables in order to add their own data, there.

Using a NoSQL database works fine too. For example, you could use a document-store database like MongoDB. If you do so, plugins can easily add content without interfering with the core project. If the plugin is removed afterwards, the data can persist without interfering with the core project. If you use an SQL database, I would just recommend you not to use the same tables for the core and the plugin project. IYou may event want to use a different schema for every plugin.